# Trouble upgrading to Laravel 4.1

Tags: laravel-4

I'm having trouble upgrading to 4.1.

I've followed the upgrade guide in the docs but when I run composer update, I get the following error:
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Application::bindShared() in
>   /site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/FailConsoleServiceProvider.php
>   on line 26
>   {"error":{"type":"Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException","message":"Call
>   to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Application::bindShared()","file":"/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/FailConsoleServiceProvider.php","line":26}}Script
>   php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned
>   with an error
>
> [RuntimeException]
>   Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Foundat   ion\Application::bindShared() in /site/vendor
>   /laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/FailConsoleServiceProvider.php
>   on l   ine 26

However, if I create a new project and use the same composer.json file, it runs successfully.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is the contents of my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
        "anahkiasen/html-object": "dev-master",
        "anahkiasen/former": "dev-master",
        "laravelbook/ardent": "dev-master",
        "nesbot/Carbon": "*",
        "jasonlewis/basset": "dev-master",
        "robclancy/presenter": "1.1.*",
        "way/generators": "dev-master",
        "baum/baum": "dev-develop",
        "loic-sharma/profiler": "1.1.*",
        "thapp/jitimage": "dev-master",
        "way/generators": "dev-master",
        "jasonlewis/basset": "dev-master",
        "cartalyst/sentry": "2.0.*",
        "edvinaskrucas/notification": "1.*",
        "laravelbook/ardent": "dev-master",
        "orangehill/iseed": "dev-master",
        "greggilbert/recaptcha": "dev-master",
        "zizaco/factory-muff": "dev-master",
        "mockery/mockery": "dev-master",
        "way/phpunit-wrappers": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Comment: You have a couple `require` packages in there twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick update.  I've got it to work now.  I had a few packages in my workbench directory which each had their own composer.json file.  I had to update the require section to read:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0",
        "illuminate/support": "4.*"
    },
```